Why is Django App Not Rendering HTML Page
I am using Django version 4.2.3 to build my website for building my website. I have an Object called UE (upcoming_events) that I have added several fields to. However, these fields don't seem to be rendering when I call the object instead the words No Events render, which only happens when the upcoming_events object is empty. In order to see why this is happening, I used the Django Shell to visualize, the code post-processing. But in the visualization the code seems to populate the objects just fine, just not when rendering the object on the website.
{% extends "webapp/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class = "centerbody">
    <div class="liner">
    <!--Carousel Starts-->
    <div class = 'dive'></div>
    <div class = float_col>
      <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade span" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner carouselMargin1">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="/static/images/CarouselPictures1/canyonphoto1.jpg/" class="d-block w-100 carouselImgs" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/static/images/CarouselPictures1/canyonphoto2.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carouselImgs" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/static/images/CarouselPictures1/canyonphoto3.jpg/" class="d-block w-100 carouselImgs" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon next_button" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  
   <div class="announcements">
      <h2>Announcements</h2>
      <div class="announcement-container">
      {% for announcement in announcements %}
          <div class="announcement-item">
              <img src="{{ announcement.image.url }}" alt="{{ announcement.title }}" class="announcement-image">
              <div class="announcement-info">
                  <h3>{{ announcement.title }}</h3>
                  <p>{{ announcement.description }}</p>
                  <span class="announcement-date">{{ announcement.event_date }}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      {% empty %}
          <p>No announcements at this time.</p>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
  </div>
   <!--Carousel Ends-->
  
  <!--This cell contains the table for the main content area-->
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td height="10" width="25">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td height="160" width="126">
            <img height="120" src="https://3bac6cafdb-custmedia.vresp.com/library/1305142154/154bc2e38d/Templates/bwlogo2.gif" style="width: 110px; height: 120px;" width="110" /></td>
          <td height="10" width="36">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td font="helvetica" height="110" width="513">
            <h1 style="color:whitesmoke ; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
              UPCOMING EVENTS <span style="color:wheat;">June &amp; BEYOND</span></h1>
            <img height="9" src="https://3bac6cafdb-custmedia.vresp.com/library/1305142180/83bdb2a586/Templates/top_bar.gif" style="width: 518px; height: 15px;" width="518" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" height="28" width="700">
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <td class = "upcomingEvents" valign="top" width="700">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">

        <!--First Event-->
        <section>
          <div class = "events">
        {% for event in upcoming_events %}
           <ul>
             <li>
               <div class = "time">

                 <h2> {{ event.UE_date }}<span> {{ event.UE_time }}</span></h2>
               </div>
               <div class = "details">
                 <!-- Event Title goes here-->
                 <h3>{{ event.UE_title }} @ {{ event.UE_location }}</h3>
                 <!-- Event Content goes here-->
                  <p>
                      {{ event.UE_content }} 
                  </p>
                  <!-- Event Content goes here-->
                   <a href="/resourcePage/">View Details</a>
               </div>
               <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </li>
           </ul>
           {% empty %}
           <p>No Events</p>
           {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

Writing this from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import UE
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from webapp.models import UE

upcoming_events = UE.objects.order_by('-UE_pub_date')[:5]
context = {'upcoming_events': upcoming_events}
print(render_to_string('webapp/home.html', context))

in the Django Shell gives the following output:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" type = "text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" type = "text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js" type = "text/js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Kids in the Canyon</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="kids">
          <!--Navbar Starts-->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                        <a class="navbar-brand size" href="/home/">KITC</a>
                        <h1 class="logo" href="/home/"></h1>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                          <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="/aboutMePage/">About KITC<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="/resourcePage/"> Reference Materials </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="/mentorPage/"> Meet the Mentors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="/specialthanks/"> Special Thanks</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="/contactusPage/">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="/donate/"> Donate </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </nav>
        <!--Navbar Ends-->
        </header>
<!--Carousel Starts-->

<div class = "centerbody">
    <div class="liner">
    <!--Carousel Starts-->
    <div class = 'dive'></div>
    <div class = float_col>
      <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade span" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner carouselMargin1">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="/static/images/CarouselPictures1/canyonphoto1.jpg/" class="d-block w-100 carouselImgs" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/static/images/CarouselPictures1/canyonphoto2.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carouselImgs" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/static/images/CarouselPictures1/canyonphoto3.jpg/" class="d-block w-100 carouselImgs" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon next_button" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>

   <div class="announcements">
      <h2>Announcements</h2>
      <div class="announcement-container">

          <p>No announcements at this time.</p>

      </div>
  </div>
   <!--Carousel Ends-->

  <!--This cell contains the table for the main content area-->
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td height="10" width="25">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td height="160" width="126">
            <img height="120" src="https://3bac6cafdb-custmedia.vresp.com/library/1305142154/154bc2e38d/Templates/bwlogo2.gif" style="width: 110px; height: 120px;" width="110" /></td>
          <td height="10" width="36">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td font="helvetica" height="110" width="513">
            <h1 style="color:whitesmoke ; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
              UPCOMING EVENTS <span style="color:wheat;">June &amp; BEYOND</span></h1>
            <img height="9" src="https://3bac6cafdb-custmedia.vresp.com/library/1305142180/83bdb2a586/Templates/top_bar.gif" style="width: 518px; height: 15px;" width="518" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" height="28" width="700">
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <td class = "upcomingEvents" valign="top" width="700">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">

        <!--First Event-->
        <section>
          <div class = "events">

           <ul>
             <li>
               <div class = "time">

                 <h2> June 24<span> 9am</span></h2>
               </div>
               <div class = "details">
                 <!-- Event Title goes here-->
                 <h3>Saturday Hike @ Lincoln Woods</h3>
                 <!-- Event Content goes here-->
                  <p>
                      We are meeting at Lincoln Woods. This is the first Saturday hike after you have gotten your boots, DO NOT FORGET THEM! You want to break them in and make sure they feel comfortable. For anyone looking for a ride to Lincoln Woods Steven will be at Ella Risk at 8:45am.
                  </p>
                  <!-- Event Content goes here-->
                   <a href="/resourcePage/">View Details</a>
               </div>
               <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </li>
           </ul>

           <ul>
             <li>
               <div class = "time">

                 <h2> Sep 12 2024<span> 9am</span></h2>
               </div>
               <div class = "details">
                 <!-- Event Title goes here-->
                 <h3>Hello @ Lin</h3>
                 <!-- Event Content goes here-->
                  <p>
                      dfgdfb bdfx
                  </p>
                  <!-- Event Content goes here-->
                   <a href="/resourcePage/">View Details</a>
               </div>
               <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </li>
           </ul>

          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>



        <footer>copywrite 2019 MySite</footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5f01c6fdfb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>

As you can see the page is grabbing the UE object fields fine in the shell can someone help explain why this is not rendering the objects
This is the model UE
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.
class UE(models.Model):
    UE_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    UE_location = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    UE_time = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    UE_date = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    UE_content = models.TextField()
    UE_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

As well as the views for the upcoming_events home request
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from webapp.models import UE
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Resource  # Adjust the import according to your app structure
from .models import Announcement

#Imports UE model


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    upcoming_events = UE.objects.order_by('-UE_pub_date')[:5]  # Ensuring this query is correct
    context = {'upcoming_events': upcoming_events}  # Check the variable name here
    return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', context)


Share the Model UE.

class UE(models.Model):
UE_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
UE_location = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
UE_time = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
UE_date = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
UE_content = models.TextField()
UE_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def home(request):
upcoming_events = UE.objects.order_by('-UE_pub_date')[:5]  # Ensuring this query is correct
context = {'upcoming_events': upcoming_events}  # Check the variable name here
return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', context) # This is views for Upcoming_events as well

The template you're showing to us is webapp/home.html right? Show us the relevant url patterns for this view and mention the url you're trying to access from your browser.

What does the server send to the client? Does the server send exactly the same HTML you see in the shell but the browser has issues displaying that? I’m trying to figure out at what point the discrepancy occurs.
